# .Net error calling EXE from Process.start

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, diagnostics

I have an MVC app where I want to call an EXE from a controller action.  I use the following code.  this works fine on my local box as well as my test server.  However on my production server I get

.NET Runtime version 4.0.30319.34209 - There was a failure initializing profiling API attach infrastructure. This process will not allow a profiler to attach. HRESULT: 0x80004005. Process ID (decimal): 8332. Message ID: [0x2509].

followed by:
Application: StaffAppraisalStart.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info: System.IO.FileLoadException Stack: at StaffAppraisalStart.Program.Main(System.String[])

Security is the same.  any ideas?

```
// Use ProcessStartInfo class
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["staffevalstartexe"]);
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

startInfo.Arguments = String.Format("/oneoff:true /appraisaltypeid:{0} /duedate:{1} /userlogin:{2} ", appraisalTypeID, dateDue, reviewee);

try
{
    // Start the process with the info we specified.
    // Call WaitForExit and then the using statement will close.
    using (System.Diagnostics.Process exeProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(startInfo))
    {
        //
        StringBuilder q = new StringBuilder();
        //while (!exeProcess.HasExited)
        //{
        //    q.Append(exeProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
        //}

        exeProcess.WaitForExit();

        q.Append(exeProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());

        Log.Instance.Error(q);
    }
    um.Status = "ok";
    um.Message = "Evaluation flow started.";
}
```

Comment: I should note that if I run the exe in a command window - it works fine.

Comment: Is this on IIS, IIS Express, Cassini, or something else?

Comment: I am using IIS.  One server on IIS is fine, the other is not...all things equal as far as I can tell.

Comment: On your two different servers, what are the file permissions like on the directory that `StaffAppraisalStart.Program.Main` is trying to run on?  Do they differ?

Comment: Yes, users have read writes and the IIS app pool account is an admin on both boxes.

Comment: In fact, if I logon to the server as the app pool account, I can run the exe from the console fine.  Something with .net or IIS I guess.